# Let pandas use 0-based row number as index when reading Excel files

Tags: pandas

I am trying to use `pandas` to process a series of XLS files. The code I am currently using looks like:

```
with pandas.ExcelFile(data_file) as xls:
    data_frame = pandas.read_excel(xls, header=[0, 1], skiprows=2, index_col=None)
```

And the format of the XLS file looks like

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                   REPORT                                  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Unit: 1000000 USD                                                         |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|        |         |             |               |          Balance         |
+   ID   +  Branch + Customer ID + Customer Name +--------------------------+
|        |         |             |               | Daily | Monthly | Yearly |
+--------+---------+-------------+---------------+-------+---------+--------+
| 111111 | Branch1 | 1           | Company A     | 10    | 5       | 2      |
+--------+---------+-------------+---------------+-------+---------+--------+
| 222222 | Branch2 | 2           | Company B     | 20    | 25      | 20     |
+--------+---------+-------------+---------------+-------+---------+--------+
| 111111 | Branch1 | 3           | Company C     | 30    | 35      | 40     |
+--------+---------+-------------+---------------+-------+---------+--------+
```

Even I explicitly gave `index_col=None`, pandas still take `ID` column as the index. I am wondering the right way of making row numbers to be the index.

Comment: Why do you have `header=[0,1]`  - it looks like the header is 1 row?

Comment: My real sheet has a MultiIndex. I will fix this.

Comment: What does `df.index` show?

Comment: @ayhan `df.index` shows `Int64Index([442000118, 442000091, 442000043, 442000086, 442000086, 442000105,
            442000162, 442000147, 442000067, 442000069,
            ...
            442000069, 442000105, 442000105, 442000086, 442000043, 442000105,
            442000100, 442000086, 442000105, 442000043],
           dtype='int64', length=1317)` (from real data) but I am expecting something like `0, 1, 2, 3...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pandas currently doesn't support parsing a `MultiIndex` columns without also parsing a row index.  Related issue [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11292) - it probably could be supported, but this gets tricky to define in a non-ambiguous way.

It's a hack, but the easiest way to work around this right now is to add a blank column on the left side of data, then read it in like this.

```
pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', header=[0,1], skiprows=2).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Edit:

If you can't / don't want to modify the files, a couple options are:

1. If the data has a known / common header, use `pd.read_excel(..., skiprows=4, header=None)` and assign the columns yourself, suggested by @ayhan.
2. If you need to parse the header, use `pd.read_excel(..., skiprows=2, header=0)`, then munge the second level of labels into a `MultiIndex`.  This will probably mess up dtypes, so you may also need to do some typecasting (`pd.to_numeric`) as well.

Comment: But with this `drop=True`, I am losing the ID data. Yet if I set it to `False`, I got the 0-based range as index, but its title is "ID", while `111111` has the title `index`.

Comment: Are you adding a blank column?  To be clear, I mean opening the file in Excel, and and inserting a blank column into the file and saving it, before parsing.

Comment: Oh, no, I could not do that. I have > 10k XLS files like this (they are generated by a bank report program which I do not have privilege/nor legal to access).

Comment: In that case, you'll probably have to do a little manual munging.  I would delete the `header=[0,1]`, then construct the columns from the parsed `.columns` and row 0.

Comment: If the files in the same format it might be easier to use `skiprows=4` and assign a MultiIndex later. Because reading them as rows might mess up the dtypes.

Comment: Yes, that's a better idea.